# Java: JWT Token Generation Using a Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jwt, certificate, token

I am developing a backend application using Spring Boot with Java. I have to fulfill this requirement: when a specific controller of my application is called I have to return a JWT (created by me) to the client.
My application has a certificate that I created using an `openssl` command.
The command I used generated a `.pem` certificate which I converted to a `.crt` certificate (still using `openssl`).
This is the certificate (.pem version):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID3zCCAsegAwIBAgIUaQYkHJTPg5Xl29W18fl1FK3F034NFVDWòEMChvcNAQEL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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**I need to create a JWT token** (to be returned to the client) starting from this specific certificate that I have saved within my application. What is the easiest way to do this using Java (possibly with standard Java libraries)?
Unfortunately I am not an expert on tokens, public keys, private keys etc ... I just know that the JWT token I create must allow the client to authenticate to me when it calls new endpoints (managed by other controllers in my application, which will validate the token!)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest the following way to proceed further:

1. Follow the blog and resurrect a minimalistic running version that has JWT authentication integrated.

   https://medium.com/wolox/securing-applications-with-jwt-spring-boot-da24d3d98f83
2. Now change AuthenticationFilter class and instead of using the hardcoded key in successfulAuthentication method use the private key of your certificate. You can retrieve the private key using bouncy castle  libraries and the method defined in blog section 4.2: https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-pem-file-keys

```
public RSAPrivateKey readPrivateKey(File file) throws Exception {
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    try (FileReader keyReader = new FileReader(file);
      PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {

        PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
        byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
        return (RSAPrivateKey) factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
    }
}
```

Once you retrieve the RSAKey use the get the getEncoded() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded--)
method of retrieved RSAPRivateKey instead of KEY.getBytes() in line 54 of AuthenticationFilter class